# Is there a JQuery plugin like Spot healing tool in photoshop?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image-processing

I cant seem to find any jquery plugin that acts like spot healing tool like in photoshop. If anyone have encountered or found something like this please share.

Basically, I want to apply this in a photo editing web app where in users can upload their photo and they can remove their wrinkles or face lines, like being face lifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a job for HTML5's `<canvas>`. Check this post http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/ for some demos of photo manipulation.

To get started, you should experiment with loading image data into a `<canvas>` element, and seeing how you can read pixel data on or around the regions that you click/drag. In the case of emulating Photoshop's spot-healing tool—it's a lot to do with sampling the pixels *around* your target around, and calculating the frequency of similar pixels in a given proximity.

Best of all, `<canvas>` makes it easy to export the state of the canvas as an image. See this post : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/.

Hope that helps some.